# Search Database with Ta'amei Hamikra

Tags: tanach, internet, trop-cantillation

Does there exist an application or website that allows one to search for specific patterns with טעמי המקרא? For example, to find all occurrences of two consecutive זרקא's (as in וה' הכה כל בכור).

Comment: How good are you with regular expressions? If so you could just use regexs and any text file representation of tanakh.

Comment: Where can I find such a file, which includes the טעמים? I'm a developer so I could handle it.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65936/tanach-with-trop-as-plain-text @Bachrach44.  My first question and I never got an answer :(

Comment: (FWIW the other two double Zarkas in Torah are אבל אשמים אנחנו and את זבחיהם אשר הם זבחים. Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82327/759)

Comment: I've answered @Heshy's question in it's place - there are a few options, and most should work for this questioner too. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65936/tanach-with-trop-as-plain-text

Comment: @SZH If you do design it based on any of the above, please share it with the world!

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68137/759

Comment: @SZH You could find such text files on Sefaria. If you click on the source name to go to its table of contents, at the bottom there’s a download link. Pick a file format that’s convenient for you, and make sure you pick a format that contains trop and you’re all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any such database, but you can create the sequences on your own, since you've mentioned that you are good in programming. Therefore I suggest you to download the text, and extract all teamim into a new file (or delete all other characters, which is [acceptable](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/944731/jewish/Can-I-delete-Gds-name-on-a-computer-screen.htm) according to most authorities). With regular expressions it's very easy. You may keep verse numbering to identify the places. To download the text, the following two sites are my suggestions:

- [**Mechon Mamre**](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0.htm)
  By far the best text resource on the Internet, but it's copyrighted, and it's editing principles are a bit vague.
- [**Dovi's site on WikiSource**](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/User:Dovi/Miqra_according_to_the_Mesorah)
  It may not be perfect, but everything is documented in Hebrew, so if you don't agree with a principle, you can change it.
- [**BHS**](https://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/biblia-hebraica-stuttgartensia-bhs/read-the-bible-text/)
  It's the edition of the German Bible Society, which is one of the best scholarly editions. It's copyrighted again.

Most of these editions debate, whether one should follow more the [Keter Aram Tzova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_Codex) or the [Leningrad Codex.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_Codex) Another discussion, is to what extent should one accept the reconstruction of [Mordechai Breuer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Breuer) (who advocated the Aleppo Codex).

Answer (score 8):

[**Quantified Cantillation**](https://quantifiedcantillation.nl/) is what you need. It is designed to search the Torah for specific sequences of trop.

I can tell using it that there is one *zarka-munach-zarka* in Breishit 42:21 and one in Shmot 12:29, and a *zarka-munach-munach-zarka* in Vayikra 17:5.

Caveats:

- Torah only, not the rest of Tanach
- No searching backwards

It is [open source](https://github.com/Noleli/trop-analysis), so you are welcome to add features.

*Note: I have no affiliation with this program.*